# foreach loop adding value within the loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

It seems very basic, but I stuck on this one.

```
$value = 0;
foreach($this->products->result() as $this->product)
{
    $value += $this->product->price;
}
//$value += $this->get_order_shipping_cost($orders_id);

return $value;
```

The value supposed to get added to create total price and then outside the loop to add a shipping cost, but for some reason my loop is returning only the first value, so I am overwriting something somewhere.

Comment: `$this->products->result()` what is this ? is it an array of products ?

Comment: are you sure if your loop is running to expected no. of times ? may be its running once only!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this is where the overwrite heapens:

```
foreach($this->products->result() as $this->product)
```

i don't know what you're doing before but maybe you could use a temp variable name in the for loop like this:

```
foreach($this->products->result() as $tempProduct)
{
    $value += $tempProduct->price;
}
```

hope it works ;)
greets, stefan

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a private member of your class while you only want to get the product and that's it. You don't need to use `$this->product`, just use a free variable instead, like `$product` and it should work:

```
$value = 0;
foreach($this->products->result() as $product)
{
    $value += $product->price;
}
```

Also if `products` is one of your objects, you should give it probably a method like `getTotalPrice()` which just returns the sum, like so:

```
$value = $this->products->getTotalPrice();
```

You can then use that more flexible within your code. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Fixed a missing "p" in "product".